# WebMatrix 3 project freezes when run in Visual Studio 2012, never did before?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, webmatrix

I have been using WebMatrix 3 and Visual Studio 2012 without trouble for a long time.  Starting today, every time I open a WebMatrix 3 project in VS2012 and I launch it, VS2012 hangs and shows as "Not Responding" in the Task Manager.  I can launch the project from within WebMatrix 3 and it does open the web browser and can successfully run the site's code.  But when I try to run the program in VS2012 it hangs and I have to use the Task Manager to close the VS2012 IDE.

I tried creating a new starter project and the same thing happens with it.  Note, I am able to run and debug **non**-WebMatrix 3 projects just fine, including MVC Web Roles.  I tried restarting my computer and that did not help.

I found this article on how a "blocked" file can cause this kind of behavior in strange places:

http://digioz.blogspot.com/2013/06/visual-studio-2012-freezes-or-crashes.html

But I don't know how to determine which file(s) may be blocked.  Also, I'm wondering if it's a weird problem with IIS Express.  Has anyone seen this and knows how to fix it?

UPDATE: I've noticed that it takes nearly 40 seconds to open WebMatrix 3 projects VS 2012 and it never took that long before.  After seeing a status line saying "Open Access Controls registers" in the status line, there appears to be a 30 second wait before project loading continues, a delay time curious close to the typical time-out setting for sockets.

Also, I tried switching from my default browser for IIS Express sessions from Chrome to Internet Explorer.  The project ran find.  **However**, the next time I ran it IE displayed the same "hanging" behavior as Chrome and after multiple attempts, never came back (still hangs)

Comment: you can report this issue to Webmatrix through mail webmatrixatmicrosoftdotcom